# How to show R graph from visual studio code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I installed extension for R language
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r

When i run my R code in visual studio code with (ctrl + enter) i get empty window instead of graph image.

[image]

but in visual studio 2017 it works

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ikuyadeu/vscode-R#r-session-watcher-experimental

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now it is possible.

**Step 1:**

a) Install [`httpgd`](https://github.com/nx10/httpgd) from CRAN or github. From CRAN,

*From CRAN:*

```r
install.packages("httpgd")
```

*From GitHub:*

```r
devtools::install_github("nx10/httpgd")
```

b) Install `languageserver`:

```r
install.packages("languageserver")
```

**Step 2:**

Install [R extension for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r)

**Step 3:**

From vscode setting, select `R > Plot: Use httpgd` to use for R plot.

They have done a amazing job with R extension. We can view data.frame and list in a separate data viewer in vscode.

Comment: For those who prefer changing their settings via the JSON Settings, instead of `R > Plot: use httpgd`, one can go to `View > Command Palette > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and add the following: `"r.plot.useHttpgd": true,`

Comment: this will still also show the rplot window in vs code for me (i would like it to only open in the browser) is this possible?

Comment: I'm using `httpgd` and if I run a script line by line (e.g. Ctrl+Enter) that has a plot call, VSCode will automatically open the plot viewer; but if I source the entire script (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+S or clicking on the |> in the top right corner), the plot viewer does not open. I know that I can manually open the interactive window by inputting `.vsc.attach()` into the R console, but it still shows nothing if the script was sourced rather than ran line-by-line.

Comment: I have followed these instructions, and my plots are still going to X11. I'm using VSCODE connecting to a remote server via ssh.

Comment: This package has worked pretty well for me for the last months. However, it has recently turned quite slow to display plots in the plot viewer after creating some of them (even after deleting those that appear in the window it is still slow to display them compared to the standard RStudio plot viewer). Anybody with the same issue?

Comment: VSCode randomly stopped showing the plot (calling `plot` would not show it) - calling `.vsc.attach()` fixed this!

Comment: Running `.vsc.attach()` got my plots back, but now I can resize them as I had been able to, following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817205/13089441

Answer (score 4):

It looks like its opening an external graphics window. Try putting

```
windows();plot(stuff)
```

This explicitly pushes the plot to an external window