# How do I conveniently resize a ggplot2 plot on R+VSC?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visual-studio-code

I'm in the process of learning R (I'm still a newcomer on SO as well). Being very used to using Visual Studio Code, I decided to choose that over RStudio or RStudio Cloud.

One of the best parts of RStudio was that plots automatically resized/reshaped themselves if we resized the right pane. Moreover, in the tutorials I watched, plots involving map data automatically rendered in the correct aspect ratio (as seen on physical maps).

I replicated the code to make my own plot of the world map. Unfortunately it rendered as a square shape, and resizing the right pane does not affect its shape:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkcIm.png)

Am I missing any commonly used VSC extensions which can make plots resizeable like in RStudio? (I've installed only the most downloaded extension for R, by Yuki Ueda)

If not, can I modify my code to specify the exact dimensions I need the plot to have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a [good resource](https://renkun.me/2020/06/16/using-httpgd-in-vscode-a-web-based-svg-graphics-device/).

Comment: FYI, I suggest adding at least `+ coord_quickmap()` to help control aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you @caldwellst! httpgb brought that convenience flawlessly

Comment: Thank you @r2evans! That does make working with map_data() much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the dimensions when you save the file. I usually use (approximately) the golden ratio:

```r
ggsave("./earth.png", width = 16, height = 10)
```

The ggsave function [reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html) explains how you can change units - options are `c("in", "cm", "mm", "px")`.

Comment: The universal usability of this will probably help me with other plots later on too, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can add robust plot viewing options for R in VSCode by installing the `httpgd` package and then amending your JSON settings.

First, install `httpgd` via the R console:

```
install.packages("httpgd")
```

Then, open your JSON settings in VSCode by opening the Command Palette (either via Ctrl+Shift+P or via View > Command Palette) and then searching for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)", where you'll insert the following:

```
"r.plot.useHttpgd": true
```

You can add a comma after 'true' if needed (i.e. if there are other lines below that in your JSON settings).

Following that, restart VSCode and launch the R terminal inside it, and plot something using either `ggplot2` or base R graphics:

```
plot(mtcars$mgp, mtcars$wt)
```

A plot viewer should then pop up in VSCode. You can either manually resize the window there, zoom in or out, or, my preference (particularly if I'm cycling through a series of already-plotted graphs), open it in an external browser where it'll automatically adjust to however you resize the window. After that, you can save or copy the image as needed.

Comment: This worked for me for a couple of plots, but now I'm not able to visualize any figures (I can run the `plot` command but the figure never appears). Any ideas what may be going wrong? Edit: From this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284345/how-to-show-r-graph-from-visual-studio-code), running `.vsc.attach()` fixed this issue but now I can't resize plots again