# Can't plot Hydenet (R package) in Visual Studio Code, jupyter notebook, R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, plot, jupyter-notebook

I've installed the 'Hydenet' package to R version 4.30.

Running the code

```
library(HydeNet)
w.net <- HydeNetwork(~ payoff | weather*action
                     + weather + action)
plot(w.net)
```

I get a plot on rStudio and rGui. However, the output on Visual Studio Code(Version 1.78(user)), jupyternotebook is blank.
[vscode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmpC9.jpg)
How do you think I can fix this problem?

I have tried:
[How to show R graph from visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284345/how-to-show-r-graph-from-visual-studio-code#comment125254168_68958793), httpgd
Also, when I use windows();plot(w.net), the window becomes unresponding and crashes kernel.